# Other programs used to make C/C++ desktop applications besides Visual studio?

Tags: c++, desktop

I'm unable to buy Visual studio. I'm just wondering if there's any other program besides Visual studio that can be used for developing C++ desktop applications.

Comment: Get [microsoft visual studio 11 developer preview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543). It like getting visual studio for free (although it will expire in June 30, 2012).

Comment: Do you mean an [IDE](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDE) or a GUI library (windows forms, WPF)?

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio has an [Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) edition which is free :)

Answer (score 2):

For a non-Microsoft option, there is [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offers free [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279) with all compilers, headers and tools (nmake, all compilers, really good debugger etc.) for all supported Windows platforms. It, basically, full version of VS2010 tools without IDE (you have to use command-line one way or another). By the way, it has x64 compilers that are not shipped with VS2010 Express.

As an IDE I find [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) to be terrific. The amount of features and level of their customization are simply amazing and very useful. You can, most likely, configure Eclipse to run MS SDK command-line tools from it, but I haven't checked it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Visual Studio Express 2010 from Microsoft, it is free.

Answer (score 0):

Can't go wrong with [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/express-cpp/overview).  It's free.

Answer (score 0):

Qt. You can download latest versions here: http://www.qt.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse Visual studio express should be easy and free.

And if you need something to use in linux - http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-linux-x11/

Comment: Qt in isolation is not sufficient to make C++ applications; you still need to have GCC installed. But pretty much any Linux distribution will include GCC, and many install it by default.

Comment: Yes. Many widely available distributions are including it by default !

Answer (score 0):

another non-msft option is Eclipse:
http://eclipse.org/cdt/

Answer (score 0):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) plus [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) gives you a good approximation of the Linux development environment, for free, *including* the MinGW option (i.e., using GCC to create native Windows executables), Mono, KDevelop etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Sharp Develop, DEVcpp, Mono D
but Visual Studio Express works just fine

Answer (score 0):

QT is fine and cross-plateform. There is a QTCreator IDE with MinGW but you can use a plugin for eclipse to draw your application via eclipse CDT.